# winapi analog of java's synchronized/wait()

Tags: multithreading, winapi

java's synchronized block is like windows critical section or mutex: only one thread may enter it at a time.
But there's a difference: when you call wait() inside the synchronized block, other threads gain the ability to enter the block. Not sure how to do the same in winapi.

This is not a solution:

```
LeaveCriticalSection();
// Something important may happen between these calls
WaitForSingleObject();
```

Java:

```
                    Thread 1            Thread 2            Thread 3
1
2                                       synchronized {
3                                       wait
5                   synchronized {
6                   notifyAll
7                   }
4                                       }
8                                                           synchronized {
9                                                           wait
10                                                          }
11                                      continue            not continue
```

Remy's variant:

```
                    Thread 1            Thread 2            Thread 3
1                                       EnterCriticalSection
2                                       ResetEvent
3                                       LeaveCriticalSection
4                   EnterCriticalSection
5                   SetEvent
6                   LeaveCriticalSection
7                                                           EnterCriticalSection
8                                                           ResetEvent
9                                                           LeaveCriticalSection
10                                      WaitForSingleObject WaitForSingleObject
11                                      not continue        not continue
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this tutorial](http://www.jchq.net/tutorial/07_03Tut.htm):

> A call to **wait** from within **synchronized** code causes the thread to give up its lock and go to sleep. This normally happens to allow another thread to obtain the lock and continue some processing. The **wait** method is meaningless without the use of **notify** or **notifyAll** which allows code that is waiting to be notified that it can wake up and continue executing.

In Win32 API terms, that would be the equivalent of something like this:

Waiting Thread:

```
ResetEvent(hWaitEvent);
LeaveCriticalSection(&lock);
WaitForSingleObject(hWaitEvent, INFINITE);
EnterCriticalSection(&lock);
```

Notifying Thread:

```
EnterCriticalSection(&lock);
...
SetEvent(hWaitEvent);
LeaveCriticalSection(&lock);
```

Where `hWaitEvent` is a waitable event created with `CreateEvent()`.

Comment: I have a feeling that unlock+sleep is atomic in java

Comment: You shouldn't do ResetEvent, in this case you need an event that auto resets, to avoid the race.

Comment: Then how to notifyAll?

Comment: I'm thinking of a chain of auto-reset events instead of one manual-reset event